# Send variable to EV3 via WiFi

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, wi-fi

I'm trying to connect my EV3 via Wifi to my Unity game. Is there a simple way to send a command to the EV3?

I gave the EV3 a fixed IP and I'm getting the broadcast which the device is sending. So there is a connection. Can I send a variable or something to my EV3?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to learn how to make a TCP connection to your EV3. There is a good guide on this [here](http://www.monobrick.dk/guides/how-to-establish-a-wifi-connection-with-the-ev3-brick/).

Then you need to learn about EV3 VM [bytecodes](http://ev3.fantastic.computer/doxygen/bytecodes.html) and how to send [direct commands](http://ev3.fantastic.computer/doxygen/communication.html).

Since you are using Unity, you may be able to use a pre-existing library such as the [MonoBrick Communication Library](http://www.monobrick.dk/software/monobrick/) or the [Brian Peek library](https://github.com/BrianPeek/legoev3/wiki).

To send a variable, you need to use [mailbox commands](http://ev3.fantastic.computer/doxygen/cCom.html) along with "Messaging" blocks in the EV3-G software.

Comment: this helped finding an answer. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

so... after talking to some people and having a sleeples night i switched to monobrick firmware and started a small webserver.

```
    namespace MonoBrickHelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {

            //LcdConsole.WriteLine ("Startup");

            HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();
            httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:9090/");
            httpListener.Start();

            var run = true;

            (new ButtonEvents()).EscapePressed += () => run = false;

            while (run)
            {
                var context = httpListener.GetContext();
                Process(context);
            }
        } //Main Ende


        private static void Process(HttpListenerContext context)
        {
            string reqPath = context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;


            //Console.WriteLine(reqPath);
            LcdConsole.WriteLine (reqPath);
            //

        }// Process End

    } //class Program end
}
```

i will split the url send to my ev3 and start different things. wow. 
Source: http://www.monobrick.dk/forums/topic/webserver/